# MS Teams Adaptive cards giving error after integrating it with the code as attachment

Tags: asp.net-core, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I'm trying to integrate this [Adaptive Card sample](https://adaptivecards.io/samples/ExpenseReportWithLabels.html) in my Asp.net core code but somehow it is not working and Bot is throwing an error "**Bad Request**". If i'm using simple text card then it is working fine [Sample card only text](https://adaptivecards.io/samples/FlightItinerary.html). I would request you to help me or highlight the issue which is causing the below problem.

Error Details:
[image: error]

Below is my code to attach a card.

```
 private async Task BotUserCallback(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var cardAttachment = CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment(_card);

        //turnContext.Activity.Attachments = new List<Attachment>() { cardAttachment };
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Attachment(cardAttachment), cancellationToken);
    }
private static Attachment CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment(string filePath)
        {
            var adaptiveCardJson = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            var adaptiveCardAttachment = new Attachment()
            {
                ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
                Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(adaptiveCardJson),
            };
            return adaptiveCardAttachment;
        }
```

Comment: the code looks ok to me... have you debugged to be sure the `ReadAllText` is bringing back the contents ok?

Comment: Let me check that and what if Read all text is not working? Then in that case what should be the correct method to read JSON?

Comment: The json converting etc. looks fine, but I'm only seeing the code snippet here - not able to check if the json is a valid adaptive card, if it's getting read correctly, etc. - hence my suggestion to debug through. I'd even try using a stock card off adaptivecards.io, to test

Comment: I'm not sure what's the exact i have debugged it line by line. It works CreateAdaptivecradAttachment and throws an error when it comes to sending  with this error => "operation returned an invalid status code 'badrequest'"

Comment: I have tried the stock card as well this one is also throwing same error

Comment: Try a very small adaptive card. There is a character limit, and perhaps you've just got a big card.

Comment: This card is working fine https://adaptivecards.io/samples/FlightItinerary.html

Comment: So just not your card? If so, it's most likely that there's a syntax error in your card

Answer (score 0):

Finally after debugging and deleting each and every line i got to know that it was because of the wrong Image URL. I have removed the image URL and it worked for me.